# Only the last Object is added to the ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I created a user defined data type and read data from a file. Here are the codes:

Student Class:

```
package system.data;

public class Student {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String regNumber;
private int coursework1Marks;
private int coursework2Marks;
private int finalExamMarks;
private double totalMarks;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getRegNumber() {
    return regNumber;
}

public void setRegNumber(String regNumber) {
    this.regNumber = regNumber;
}

public int getCoursework1Marks() {
    return coursework1Marks;
}

public void setCoursework1Marks(int coursework1Marks) {
    this.coursework1Marks = coursework1Marks;
}

public int getCoursework2Marks() {
    return coursework2Marks;
}

public void setCoursework2Marks(int coursework2Marks) {
    this.coursework2Marks = coursework2Marks;
}

public int getFinalExamMarks() {
    return finalExamMarks;
}

public void setFinalExamMarks(int finalExamMarks) {
    this.finalExamMarks = finalExamMarks;
}

public double getTotalMarks() {
    totalMarks = (coursework1Marks * 0.2) + (coursework2Marks * 0.2) + (finalExamMarks * 0.6);
    return totalMarks;
}
```

}

And the main coding:

```
public class MainInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private File studentFile = new File(".\\StudentMarks.txt");
private PrintWriter printWriter = null;
private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
public ArrayList<Student> studentDetails = null;
private Scanner input = null;
private int counter = 0;

/**
 * Creates new form MainInterface
 */
public MainInterface() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    studentDetails = new ArrayList<Student>();
    ReadStudentDetails(studentDetails);
}
private void ReadStudentDetails(ArrayList<Student> studentDetails) {
    ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
    Student student = new Student();

    try {
        input = new Scanner(studentFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainInterface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    while(input.hasNext()){
        counter++;
        String str = input.nextLine();
        strList.add(str);
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

    for (String item : strList) {
        int x = 0;
        String[] arr = item.split(":");

        student.setFirstName(arr[0]);
        student.setLastName(arr[1]);
        student.setRegNumber(arr[2]);
        student.setCoursework1Marks(Integer.parseInt(arr[3]));
        student.setCoursework2Marks(Integer.parseInt(arr[4]));
        student.setFinalExamMarks(Integer.parseInt(arr[5]));

        studentDetails.add(student);
    }

}
```

There no syntax errors given. But When I try to print the elements in the ArrayList as,

```
    for(Student item: studentDetails){
        System.out.println(item.getFirstName());
    }
```

It gives out only the last record from the file, (which has 3 records). Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you ever try to debug this code? You will find problem in storing your `Student` object in ArrayList.  This is the basic things that you have to keep in mind before writing this type of for loop or code.

Comment: what happened here? where did the code go? the question was fine and there were many answer which solved your problem. Can you fix it up again? It's all blank

Answer (score 6):

The same student object is reused, because Java passes a reference to an object in the call that adds the student to the list. In other words, the original student is passed each time. The solution is to create a new Student for each call.

```
for (String item : strList) {
    int x = 0;
    String[] arr = item.split(":");

    Student student = new Student();

    student.setFirstName(arr[0]);
    student.setLastName(arr[1]);
    student.setRegNumber(arr[2]);
    student.setCoursework1Marks(Integer.parseInt(arr[3]));
    student.setCoursework2Marks(Integer.parseInt(arr[4]));
    student.setFinalExamMarks(Integer.parseInt(arr[5]));

    studentDetails.add(student);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create new instance of `Student` object inside the `for` loop

like this

```
for (String item : strList) {
        int x = 0;
        String[] arr = item.split(":");
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setFirstName(arr[0]);
        student.setLastName(arr[1]);
        student.setRegNumber(arr[2]);
        student.setCoursework1Marks(Integer.parseInt(arr[3]));
        student.setCoursework2Marks(Integer.parseInt(arr[4]));
        student.setFinalExamMarks(Integer.parseInt(arr[5]));

        studentDetails.add(student);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are always using the same student object.You have to put Student student = new Student(); inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

try moving `Student student = new Student();` inside the for loop:

```
 for (String item : strList) {
    int x = 0;
    String[] arr = item.split(":");
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirstName(arr[0]);
    student.setLastName(arr[1]);
    student.setRegNumber(arr[2]);
    student.setCoursework1Marks(Integer.parseInt(arr[3]));
    student.setCoursework2Marks(Integer.parseInt(arr[4]));
    student.setFinalExamMarks(Integer.parseInt(arr[5]));

    studentDetails.add(student);
}
```

hope this helps.